# Cron job doing MySQL database back up not working when append date to the file name

Tags: cron, mysql-backup, datestamp

I'm using shared cPanel hosting.

When I enter the following cron job command it works:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -p'pazzword' my_db > /backup/database.sql
```

But when I try to add date stamp to the file name, it doesn't generate .sql files.

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -p'pazzword' my_db > /backup/database_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").sql
```

I can't find cron job error logs, have I made an error in my command?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Finally I managed to fix the problem.

You need to escape **%** with **** .

So the working cron job command will look like this:

```
 */5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -p'pazzword' my_db > /backup/database_$(date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d").sql
```